# what is the CLSID and PROG ID of Microsoft.sqlserver.Management.Smo

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, visual-c++, smo

Can any Body tell me wher can i get CLSID and ProgID of Smo  library??

As for DMO it is givenn in a Header file by Microsoft.But i am not finding any Header file

related to smo.

What is the CLSID and ProgID of Smo ??

ANy Hep in this regard greately Appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

603F0A84-5631-3CA0-BCE0-C96597C2C1A0

Answer (score 0):

Use [#import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(VS.71).aspx), it will generate all the CLSID, IID and interface smart pointers for you.